# Listing tables used in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have nearly 800 SQL scripts ranging medium to complex SQLs.
Database is Oracle.

I need list of tables used in each of these scripts. Each script contains numerous with clauses, joins and subqueries. Is there a easier way to achieve this?

Thanks
LN

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

first store all queries to 1 table -scripts- with the columns - script_name, script_text
then this could work:

```
select script_name,  script_text, object_name
  from scripts s
  join dba_objects do
    on 1 = 1
 where 1 = 1
   and instr(upper(s.script_text), upper(do.object_name)) > 0
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like a bad idea at all. Could be *improved* by filtering on OBJECT_TYPE.

Comment: Exactly I was going to say the same !! Thanks very much Yusuf !! I have another small road block  rather i missed to mention. Some of the objects are having different server hosts altogether. Do you think of there a way to achieve this?

Comment: your point is that: these queries are running in different DBs or they are all in the same DB but there are dblinks inside the queries? If the first one, then export all dba_objects and store them in 1 temp table in one of the DB. And do these analysis. If the second one, then you can union all statement to query above and  search for the records who has dblinks -  s.script_text like '@' and also use instr function in select statement to get object_name.

Comment: This will cause some *false positive* e.g. for the commented out tables and also match `tab`, `my_tab`and `my_tab_big` if you use `my_tab_big_table` only. Anyway a good cheep starting point, but the query can be written without the *ugly* `1=1`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `explain plan` for each of the statements and then check the content of `plan_table`. But it:

- doesn't count views (plan table shows base tables of the view) and scalar functions
- should be adapted for dblinks
- should be thoroughly tested with local PL/SQL declarations (`with function`) and functions in other schemas
- has influence of query rewrite and baselines

Below is an example:

> ```
> begin
>   for i in 1..10 loop
>     execute immediate
>       'create table t'
>       || i || '( id int)';
>   end loop;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create view v_test
> as
> select *
> from t5
>   join t6
>   using(id)
> ```

> ```
> create function f_tab
> return sys.odcinumberlist
> pipelined
> as
> begin
>   null;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> explain plan for
> select *
> from t1, t2, t3, t4,
>   /*View*/
>   v_test,
>   /*Pipelined function*/
>   table(f_tab())
> ```

> ```
> select
>   object_owner,
>   object_name,
>   object_type
> from plan_table
> where
>   (object_owner, object_name) in (
>     select
>       f.owner,
>       f.object_name
>     from all_objects f
>     where f.object_type in (
>       'TABLE'
>       , 'VIEW'
>     )
>   ) or (object_name, object_type) in (
>     select
>       f.object_name,
>       'PROCEDURE'
>     from user_objects f
>     where f.object_type in (
>       'FUNCTION'
>       , 'PROCEDURE'
>     )
>   )
> order by 1
> ```
>
> ```
> OBJECT_OWNER                | OBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_TYPE
> :-------------------------- | :---------- | :----------
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T1          | TABLE      
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T2          | TABLE      
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T3          | TABLE      
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T4          | TABLE      
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T5          | TABLE      
> FIDDLE_TQYMTNVUFUWHRWJEENKX | T6          | TABLE      
> null                        | F_TAB       | PROCEDURE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=454b5c68bc6510b5891f2f3f1a95d52e)*

Anyway, I think that this sort of task should be addressed to SQL parser in any way instead of any string manipulation, because only parser exactly knows what objects were used

Comment: This will provide a better result than the text scanning, but need to account for *indexes* and probably also *partitions*.

Comment: I agree. I am going to try both the options and see how the results compare to each other. Thanks very much !!